# Cannot add folders to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have signed up with Ubuntu One (20GB) and I'm having the following issue:

I basically cannot add folders through the panel interface. I have been able to add five folders so far, but I'd like to add some more (yes, they are inside the home folder). I don't get no errors, but nothing is added to the folders list.

By using the command line interface like this

```
 u1sdtool --create-folder /home/alex/Web
```

it basically hangs. Nothing happens.
If I then list the folders with command line, my folder is not there.

Any idea?

(I'm on 12.10)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue was related with the high number of files that needed indexing.

Adding folders **one by one** and waiting for indexing and uploading for each, apparently solved the issue.

Now added folders can be seen right away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by reinstalling UbuntuOne following the instructions here
https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-one/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding them in the file manager (nautilus)?

If you create a normal folder then:
Right click the folder -> Ubuntu One -> Synchronize this folder.

Comment: What actually happened was that i clicked something, ubuntu One kind of logged me out, upon new login it was like on new setup, got me to choose folders, I could add them from there, but now it's hanging since one hour saying 'gathering information'... I love ubuntu, but One seems like one bugged piece of software. Quite the unloved child.

Comment: I left it overnight 'gathering information' and in the morning still it was gathering information. I then tried to add as you said, but nothing happens. It's quite broken and I think the only folder working properly is the Ubuntu One folder, like a dropbox.

Comment: You might want to reinstall Ubuntu One client. I have never had such problems with Ubuntu One.

Comment: It happens on two computers already :( or rather, on two computers and two different distros too (on one computer i tried lubuntu 12.10, erased, installed ubuntu 12.10, and same issue... on the other pc, i have 12.04)

Comment: Okey, well that is really unfortunate! If you dont get any good solutions here, goto Ubuntu One: Support: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/